# LM317 Vout drops on load

Tags: voltage-regulator, voltage-reference, lm317

I built a very basic circuit to get around 5.5V from a +15V source

I have a 220 Ohm between Adj and Vout and one 470 Ohm, one 220 Ohm and two 100 Ohm in parallel between Gnd and Adj summing up to about 740 Ohm
that should give me about 5.45V between Vout and Gnd.

With a 1.5k Ohm Load between Vout and Gnd I get 5.5V. However with a 470 Ohm Load I only get about 3.7V.

Putting in 100nF capacitors between Vin and Gnd and Vout Gnd did not help

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4ffwb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Any Ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Chech the input voltage to the LM317 while the 470 Ohm load is connected.  It must be higher than about 7.5 volts for the LM317 to maintain regulation.

Comment: Input voltage with 470 Ohm load is +15V coming from a Lab PSU

Comment: Is the LM317 getting hot?

Comment: Not at all I even measured every resistor and jumper wire used and tried 3 different LM317

Comment: Could you draw a diagram of your schematic with the tool and edit your question?

Comment: added the scematic

Comment: Are you sure your lab supply is not set to current limit at a very low current? Did you **actually measure** the input voltage? You said you put 100nF on Vin but show it on Vadj.

Comment: Sorry I failed on the schematic, the 100nF is between Vin and Gnd. Fixed this in the schematic. I did indeed *measure* the input Voltage it's +15V. The supply has a current limit but it's not in limit mode and the limit is at about .5A

Comment: Where did you get the LM317? Was it sitting around? out of the package crisp and new?

Comment: At conrad it's a LM317LZ from ST in a TO-92 package

Comment: The next step is to measure the voltages along the R1 - R5 resistor chain. Add them into your schematic using the 'NODE' symbol.

Comment: This issue sounds similar to this one where the regulator was installed backwards, may or may not be the issue here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/24944/lm317-voltage-regulator-circuit-drops-vout-on-load?rq=1

Comment: Poor layout can cause oscillation, which will lower the output voltage.

Comment: @CoreyF I read that post I double checked the pinout of the LM317 in the datasheet

Comment: @xuma202 Fair enough, I ran the calculations front the schematic you provided and I'm out of ideas other than a bad IC which can be checked by comparing results from using a different one.

Comment: @xuma202, be sure to check the LM317L datasheet. The pins are not the same as for LM317.

Comment: I did not notice ST was drawing the LM317 from the bottom and indeed connected it backwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you have swapped the input and adj pins by having the LM317L reversed.

[image]

Note that the view is **from the top** looking down through the plastic (dashed lines for the pins).

Connected backwards, it perhaps acts as a sort of zener breaking down at 9V or so with some resistance in series.

Answer (score 0):

R1 must have 1.25 V between Vout-Vadj to be functional. If not, then it is not working per spec.

By ratios 220/Rtot*Vout =1.25V. and your Rtot looks correct for 5.5V.

So the criteria for 1.25 is not correct, either bad IC or routing.

Comment: Indeed I only have around 200mV between Vout and VAdj